# It's possible to download video from youtube with URLSession swift 4?

Tags: swift3, swift4

I want to download video from Youtube with link on URLSession. It's possible to download video from youtube with URLSession swift 4 ?

The problem is I can't find link to download video. I mean when I copy the link video from youtube and past to URL session it download HTML content.

Comment: What happened when you tried it? What's the actual problem?

Comment: The problem is I can't find link to download video. I mean when I copy the link video from youtube and past to URL session it download HTML content.

Comment: Then that is what your question should say.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to download the video by simply pasting the video link. Downloading the link will result in downloading the webpage but not the content. To tap into the content of the page, you have to go through some algorithms to decode and extract the direct link for video, thumbnail, etc. There are some open source libraries that you can use to help you decode the video page link and would give you the direct video link (direct link you can download). If you are developing in swift, I would suggest you look into [XCDYouTubeKit](https://github.com/0xced/XCDYouTubeKit). I have personally used it and I find it really good. If you'd like a ready made app, feel free to use my open source app - [YouTag](https://github.com/youstanzr/YouTag) - which utilizes XCDYouTubeKit Library.

Hope this helps you :)

Comment: Glad to help:) if that answers your question please accept my answer

Comment: for now I not yet to test it. I 'll accept for you if it work with the latest version. However thank you for your answer.